# Purge Varnish Cache for specific URL with CURL

Tags: magento2, varnish

I have [checked this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303382/purge-specific-link-from-magento-2-varnish) but it did not help. On top of that, I receive an extra error on that question.

When I run this:

```
curl -X PURGE -H 'X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: .*' https://www.example.com/my-url
```

It throws this error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .*'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>400 X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error 400 X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required</h1>
    <p>X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: 380572434</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looks like `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .*'` is not able to connect to host.

Any suggestions to clear this specific URL's cache only?

**WORKED**

I had to use double quotes:

```
curl -X PURGE -H "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: .*" https://www.example.com/my-url
```

Comment: For some reason your `curl` is seeing the quoted `X-Magento-Tags-Pattern` as the URL instead of the header. Add the `-v` parameter to `curl` to debug. When I run your command, the header is sent nicely and `curl` doesn't complain about the host.

Comment: I had to use a double quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use double quotes:

```
curl -X PURGE -H "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: .*" https://www.example.com/my-url
```